# Rails Action mailer for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, smtp, actionmailer

I am using a Gmail account for my production environment as I can't afford paying for a mail host. I use the account to send emails to people using action mailer. Problem is my host is heroku and as you know it's not always the same exact server. So each time the server changes I have to go visit this  [http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)  to enable dealing [https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)  turned on.

Each time the dyno restarts I have to do that all over again. What are my options and what should I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: use [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) instead

Comment: I am afraid I will hit the 10k mark fast. Any alternatives? Thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `sendgrid` which is a heroku addon for a production mailer which works well with heroku.

Followed this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

You have to take care though:

1. In the `xxxxxxx_mailer.rb` set the `default from: "xxx@xxx.com" to a valid email address.
2. Add this as well to your production.rb `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.example.com' }`

`